# Foreach binding with 'afterAdd' causes the whole template to draw again on insertions

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I'm trying to automatically scroll the contents of my page whenever a new item is added to a list.

At first, I tried using `afterAdd` in the `foreach` binding, since it seemed to be what I was looking for. So I did something like this:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: { data: contents, 
                          afterAdd: function(e) { e.scrollIntoView(false); } }">
    <li data-bind="text: field"></li>
</ul>
```

[Here is a fiddle with the code](http://jsfiddle.net/julealgon/suqsLqLa/2/)

If you try that, you will notice what to me is some very weird behavior. For every call, knockout seems to be recreating the whole template from scratch again. So in the first 'add', one element is added. On the second add, the first and second are added again, and so on.

I could not make that work no matter what I tried, but this [version using `afterRender`](http://jsfiddle.net/julealgon/suqsLqLa/3/) worked:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: { data: contents, 
                          afterRender: function(e) { e[1].scrollIntoView(false); } }">
    <li data-bind="text: field"></li>
</ul>
```

The difference is that instead of getting the element directly, I'm getting an array of all DOM elements.

You can test the behavior in the fiddle too. If you keep adding items, when the screen reaches the bottom, it will start to scroll to the newly added element.

Why can't I use `afterAdd` for this? What exactly is happening there with the crazy behavior?

Comment: I'm seeing an error in the console in the `afterAdd` version: `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

Comment: Seems that `afterAdd` is being passed _just_ the text node rendered in the bound span, rather than the entire contents, whereas `afterRender` is given all the elements, and the first one is the `li`, which does have the `scrollIntoView` method

Answer (score 1):

It would appear that `afterAdd` is called once for each element that's actually rendered.  In your example fiddle, it is called 3 times each time an item is added.  The first time (for me, in Chrome at least) was with a text node, which doesn't have a `scrollIntoView` method.  The simplest solution is to check before calling the method, though this still seems like a fudge to me:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: { data: contents, afterAdd: function(e) { if (e.scrollIntoView) e.scrollIntoView(false); } }">
    <!-- ... --->
</ul>
```

This way, it will only attempt to scroll elements that have the method available on them.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gbzf7a3b/1/)

Comment: Damn it... you are right. I started doing a bit more testing after your comments and yeah, I'm calling the method for some text instances. I'm very bad at javascript, so I did not know you could test the presence of a method like that. I figured now I could do something like `$(e).filter('li')[0].scrollIntoView(false)`, but I also don't like it because it's so verbose. Your test does feel weird still, but it is concise. I'll go with that for the moment.